# In C, why certain function name prefix of "_ _" (double underscore)

Tags: c

I am reading the source code of [open-iscsi](https://github.com/open-iscsi/open-iscsi). In this source files I see few functions start with prefix "__". Whats the reason behind naming a function with double underscore as prefix in general in C language?

Example: In the file usr/iscsi_sysfs.c, the function name `static int __get_host_no_from_hwaddress(void *data, struct host_info *info)`

Thanks for reading the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are reserved identifiers. Using them guarentees no naming collisions with user's code (assuming the users follow the convention).

> **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**
> ....
>   All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>   underscore are always reserved for any use.

Such names should **not** appear in third-party libraries, see **@M.M.**'s comment.

Comment: That's reserved for use by the implementation. Third party libraries shouldn't really be doing that.

Comment: But everyone does use underscores. This is a pretty rich part of the standard.

Comment: @self Do you mean everyone using leading `_X` or `__` in names? I would not say so, although indeed it happens.